# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose the following are true:

$\bullet$ The probability of a random kindergartener having chicken pox at any given time is $2\%$.

$\bullet$ Among kindergarteners who have chicken pox, $75\%$ have red spots.

$\bullet$ Among kindergarteners who do not have chicken pox, $1\%$ have red spots.

Given that David, a kindergartener, has red spots, what is the probability that David has chicken pox?

---

My reasoning so far is from 1000 kids, 20 have chicken pox and 15 of those children have red spots. So then the answer would be 15/1000 = 3/200. I'm not sure that this address the third bullet point though.

Comment: Try drawing a tree diagram, it makes things much more obvious. Your first branch will be "Has chickenpox/Doesn't have chicken pox" and the second branch will be "Has red spots/Doesn't have red spots".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My reasoning so far is from 1000 kids, 20 have chicken pox and 15 of those children have red spots. So then the answer would be 15/1000 = 3/200. I'm not sure that this address the third bullet point though.

Your reasoning is correct that: of $1000$ kids, $20$ kids are expected to have the pox and $15$ of these to show spots.

To address the third bullet point, you also need to note that we expect $980$ kids *not to* have the pox and $9.8$ of these *to* have spots (on average).

So of the $15+9.8$ kids who have red spots only $15$ have the pox.   Thus the probability of having the chicken pox given red spots is:$$\frac{15}{24.8} = \frac{75}{124}$$

---

More formally: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(C\mid R) & = \frac{\mathsf P(C\cap R)}{\mathsf P(C\cap R)+\mathsf P(\neg C \cap R)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{2\%\times 75\%}{2\%\times 75\% + 98\%\times 1\%}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{75}{124}
\\[1ex] & \approx 60.5\%
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

P(pox) = 0.02

P(spots|pox) = 0.75

P(spots|no pox) = 0.01

P(spots,pox) = P(pox)P(spots|pox) = 0.015

P(spots, no pox) =  P(no pox)P(spots|no pox) = 0.0098

P(spots) = P(spots,pox) + P(spots,no pox) = 0.0248

P(pox|spots) = P(spots,pox)/p(spots) = 0.6048